# Laravel pivot table attach duplicates many times

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-7

In my project, there's a competition that includes many teams, and an organizer can upload many documents/photos to a competition assigning them to a team, so I decided to make a `files` table to store all the file data while there are separate tables for `compactions`, and `teams`  and I made a pivot table as competition_file with fields  `competition_id` , `team_id` , `file_id`, and `type` as below image

[image]

Here's how my UI looks like

[image]

In this form, you're able to upload multiple images/documents photos are uploaded by an Ajax request. The form gets the response `uuid's` of the images uploaded in the files table and submits again to the `store functions` in the documents table.

Here's the store function of the `Files` controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $fh = new FileUploader($request);
    $fh->toDisk('public');

    if ($request->has('upload_dir')) {
        $fh->saveToDir($request->input('upload_dir', 'files'));
    }

    $result = $fh->upload();
    if ($result->isSuccessful()) {
        $file = new File([
            'key' => Uuid::generate(4),
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'allow_public_access' => false,
            'original_filename' => $result->getOriginalFilename(),
            'file_path' => $result->filePath(),
            'file_disk' => $result->diskName(),
            'file_url' => $result->publicUrl(),
            'file_size_bytes' => $result->getFileSize(),
            'uploaded_by_user_id' => (auth()->id()) ?? auth()->id()
        ]);
        $file->category = $request->input('category', 'general');
        $file->save();

        return response()->apiSuccess([
            'uuid' => $file->uuid,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->apiError('Failed to upload file. Try with another file or contact admin.');
}
```

Here's the relationship in the `Teams` modal

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(File::class,'competition_file')->wherePivot('type', 'image');
}
```

And here's the store function of the documents controller

```
   public function store($competition, Request $request, Team $entity)
    {

    
    $uuid = $request->photos;
    File::whereIn('uuid', $uuid)->update(['name' => $request->name, 'description'=>$request->description]);        

     

     if ($request->has('photos') && is_array($request->photos)) {
        $files = $this->filesRepo->getByUuids($request->photos);

      

        if ($files->isNotEmpty()) {

           
            $entity->documents()->attach($files->pluck('id'),['team_id'=>$request->team,'competition_id'=>$competition]);
          

          
        }
    } }
```

I need to know what's wrong with the pivot table, I was unable to use `sync` and I used `attach`, and when I store the data to the and attach the relationships, it duplicates if I have selected more than 1 image/document, as shown in the image below

[image]

while I have selected only 3 images, I get duplicates'

here's how the pivot table looks like after store

[image]

Here are the migration files for the `competition_file` table

```
    class CreateCompetitionFileTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('competition_file', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('competition_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('competitions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('file_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('files')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->bigInteger('team_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('type')->default('image')->comment('image|attachment');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('competition_file');
    }
}
```

Somebody, please help me out.

Comment: `attach` will always create a new record on pivot table. Why the sync did not work - what was the error? Have you tried `save()` https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#saving-additional-data-on-a-pivot-table

Comment: @Donkarnash when i used `sync` i got this error 
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'competition_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `competition_file` (`file_id`, `team_id`) values (145, ?))`

Comment: Can you post the migration file for competition_file table

Comment: @Donkarnash I updated the question with migration file

Comment: Have you tried to check the value for $competition received in the store method parameter - `($competition)` that must be a null value received. Check and see. You can also access it via $request->route('competition') if it's a route parameter. Post the route for the store method

Comment: You always use `sync()` to update many-to-many relationships for this reason. If you don't always need `competition_id` on every entry, then run a migration making it nullable.

Comment: @Donkarnash i tried `$request->route('competition');` and i got the competition id, 
i have posted the store method above already please check under `And here's the store function of the documents controller` where i have used the `attach`

Comment: So now try using `$entity->documents()->sync($files->pluck('id'),['team_id'=>$request->team,'competition_id'=>$request->route('competition')]);` should work

Comment: @Donkarnash i get the same error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'team_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `competition_file` (`competition_id`, `file_id`) values (?, 147))`

Comment: Check the value for $request->team should not be null. By the way you are using method injection for Team $entity isn't that the team which you want to associate? Can't you use $entity->id instead of $request->id? And aren't you using the $entity->documents() relation to sync - so you probably don't need to supply team_id

Comment: Syncing via relation doesn't need the team_id to be supplied separately, you can try `$entity->documents()->sync($files->pluck('id'), ['competition_id' => $request->route('competition')]);`